# API for changing Gmail password

Tags: gmail

I have been using MailSystem.NET library for retrieving emails from my Gmail account using C#.NET. I was wondering if this library or Google provide an API to change the password programmatically.

Comment: @pst just out of curiosity, why not?

Comment: Jasonw I checked the links. The documentation google has offered is kind of confusing. The AppsService object expects a domain. I'm not a domain administrator. I just need to be able to change my gmail password programmatically.

Comment: @HamidRashidi Then Google does provide API of the possibility to altered the password programmatically. If you want to change your password, then change it in the gmail web interface?

Comment: I have a situation where I need to change the password programmatically and periodically. I cannot use the web interface.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible through the [UserEntry](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/provisioning/#updating_a_user_account) object. Check out on the .NET tab in the link. Also, read into this [link](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.org.google.api.apps/1577) on the discussion done on how to do it programmatically.