# Can I change password of my social media accounts by using their APIs?

Tags: facebook, twitter, google-plus

I wanna know if is posible or someone know if I can change password of my account in Facebook, Twitter and Google+ by using their own APIs?

Comment: Facebook has not API for it

Comment: Twitter doesn't have an API for it.

Comment: Thank you for your comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this has been answered for google (gmail) at the following link: [API for changing Gmail password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10441675/api-for-changing-gmail-password)

Also, it will vary from site to site, so do some research for each site you are interested in changing your password(s) for.

FYI, please do some research first before asking a question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Ok. I will take into account your comments and answers. I will be better with the questions. I was not sure about the information with APIs in the developers pages of those social networks